# How to add action and novalidate attribute to form tag using Crispy form

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm building an app using Django. For form, I use Crispy forms package to render forms.

In templates, I render form like this

```
{% crispy form %}
```

I get this result:

```html
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="..."> 
 <div id="div_id_city" class="form-group">
   <label for="id_city" class=" requiredField">
   City<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> 
   <div class=""> <input type="text" name="city" maxlength="255" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_city"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-row form-row">
   <div class="from-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
     <div id="div_id_energy_cons_before" class="form-group">
       <label for="id_energy_cons_before" class=" requiredField">
       Energy consumption before intervention<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> 
       <div class=""> <input type="number" name="energy_cons_before" step="any" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_energy_cons_before"> </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
     <div id="div_id_energy_cons_after" class="form-group">
       <label for="id_energy_cons_after" class=" requiredField">
       Energy consumption after intervention<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> 
       <div class=""> <input type="number" name="energy_cons_after" step="any" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_energy_cons_after"> </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

I wonder how can I add `action` and `novalidate` attributes to the `form` tag.

**Note:** I know that there are other methods to render forms using Crispy forms. But I want to use this method because I defined in `form.py` the layout of my form (using Crispy forms layouts) something like this:

```py
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
   [...]
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper()
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
           'city',
           Row(
               Column('energy_cons_before', css_class='from-group col-md-6'),
               Column('energy_cons_after', css_class='form-group col-md-6'),
               css_class='form-row',
           ),
           ...
           Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
       )
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: This link may helpful you: [django-crispy-forms](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `form_tag = false` to your form helper. You can then add the form tag manually to your template to add your extra requirements via the template?

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html#formhelper-with-a-form-attached-default-layout

Answer (score 1):

in your ExampleForm, you can try:

```
   self.helper.attrs = {"novalidate": ''}
   self.helper.form_tag = True
```